# Rewrite rule custom 301 redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, redirection, 301-redirect

I have link like this:

```
www.example.com/full-image/folder/subfolder/image-name.jpg-some-custom-keywords.html
```

and I need 301 redirection to url like this:

```
www.example.com/folder/subfolder/image-name.jpg.html?some-custom-keywords.html
```

I need to remove "**full-image/**" and to change "**.jpg-**" to "**.jpg.html?**"

I managed to write url redirection to remove "full-image/" like this:

```
RewriteRule ^full-image/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

but how to change "**.jpg-**" to "**.jpg.html?**" ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along those lines should do (untested):

```
RewriteRule ^full-image/(.*).jpg-(.*)$ /$1.jpg.html?$2 [L,R=301]
```